# Investigate significance of adonis (Permanova) coefficients

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, permutation-test, vegan

`Adonis`' output for an analysis of multivariate variation between groups includes coefficients for all variables of the dataset.

Is anyone aware of a way to calculate which of the variables "significantly" contributes to the variance between the groups in question, based on these coefficients? Or let's say, is there a way to determine which variables do not contribute and could be excluded from the dataset?

The aim would be to find a way to run subsequent analyses on a multivariate dataset, which only includes variables which are separating the groups we are interested in.

I thought about principal components, but then I wouldn't know how to determine a threshold to exclude variables. Or how to even approach this.

This is how the vignette describes the `coefficients` section of the `adonis` output:

> matrix of coefficients of the linear model, with rows representing sources of variation and columns representing species; each column represents a fit of a species abundance to the linear model. These are what you get when you fit one species to your predictors. These are NOT available if you supply the distance matrix in the formula, rather than the site x species matrix

So, in essence, the question is how I would be able to extract which species contribute significantly to the linear model underlying the permanova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://mibwurrepo.github.io/Microbial-bioinformatics-introductory-course-Material-2018/multivariate-comparisons-of-microbial-community-composition.html

if "group" is the name of the group vairable, use `coefficients(permanova.res)["group",]`

Coefficients are NOT available if you supply the distance matrix in the formula to adonis. Instead, supply the data table and calculate the distance using adonis directly.

For example:

```
 permanova.res <-  adonis(t(species_table) ~  group, data=data_table, permutations=1000, method = "bray")
```

However, these don't provide variables that "significantly" separate the groups, just coefficients.

Comment: I figured this out by myself eventually and forgot to edit and give the answer as an edit to the question. I accepted yours, so if anyone might be looking for this, they can find it here.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen people use `adonis` to determine which species contribute to the differences in community. That's not to say it's not possible - presumably it's more likely to be the ones with larger coefficients.

Other types of analysis might be more useful, as they look at this question more specifically e.g. indicator species analysis (different versions available in the `indicspecies` and `TITAN2` packages) and simper.

You could also look into joint species distribution modelling, which more specifically models the abundance of each species whilst incorporating between species correlations (available in various packages: `mvabund`, `boral`, `gllvm`).

Comment: what exactly does term refer to here?

Comment: Predictors in the model. Is that not what you mean by "variables" in your question?

Comment: No, variables refer to the different "species", variables of the multivariate data set with one outcome. See, the predictor in this case would be for example "group", and the composition of variables between groups may differ. I am interested in how much each variable contributes to the differences between groups.

Comment: ok, I edited my answer accordingly